# UIAlertView in Landscape mode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0

I have set my iPhone in the landscape mode but when I try to display the UIAlertView its come in the portrait mode. How it will display in landscape mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following code in applicationDidFinishLaunching in applicationdelegate.m file

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft animated: NO ];
```